# PHP conditional based on whether Ustream channel is currently broadcasting?

Tags: php, video-streaming

Is it possible for me to use the Ustream API and PHP to change the content of a website if a particular channel is currently broadcasting. For example, I'd like to show youtube videos on my page unless the Ustream is broadcasting, then the stream would be shown instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Ustream API. If you can get a response saying 'No stream currently airing' then you can do it.